# jquery, how to use multiple ajax requests?

Tags: jquery, ajax

i have this situation inside `xxx.php`:

```
<form id="s">
<input id="q"/>
<input type="submit" href="Search!"/>
</form>
<div id="r"></div>
```

inside the `foo.php` i have another form:

```
<form id="ss">
<input id="qq"/>
<input type="submit" href="Search!"/>
</form>
<div id="rr"></div>
```

and inside the `yyy.php` i have another form:

```
<form id="sss">
<input id="qqq"/>
<input type="submit" href="Search!"/>
</form>
<div id="rrr"></div>
```

inside `javascript.js` i have :

```
$('#s').submit(function(evt) {
evt.preventDefault();
$.ajax({
url: 'foo.php',
data: {
    query: $('#q').val()
  },
success: function(data) {
    $('#r').html(data);
  }
});
return false;
});

$('#ss').submit(function(evt) {
evt.preventDefault();
$.ajax({
url: 'yyy.php',
data: {
    query: $('#qq').val()
  },
success: function(data) {
    $('#rr').html(data);
  }
});
return false;
});
```

what happens is that when i submit the first form the second one load in, so now i have 2 forms (as expected) but when i submit the second form the third one doesn't load using ajax, but it redirects to it by refreshing.

so basically i need to do as many ajax loads as i can

any ideas?

thanks

Comment: This probably isn't the problem, but why do you have HREFs in your SUBMIT INPUTs? Seems to me you should have VALUEs instead.

Comment: did you handle $('#sss').submit(function(evt) {});

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use Live events for things you dynamically load in so in your case:

```
$("#ss").live('submit', function (e) {
   // Code here
});
```

You only need to use live events for things that are not always in the DOM. If you request pages through ajax and then intent to use them you will need to use live events.

See : http://api.jquery.com/live/
For a little more detail

Comment: @HenryGarle  you don't _have_ to - you can simply manually bind events to the new elements once they're loaded.

Comment: ups, it started working, looks like the first ajax has to stay like i set it up

Comment: You are right Alnitak, you could place all the bindings into a function that you can trigger when a page is loaded but there are some inherent problems with that. If you have bindings for things that appear multiple times on a page and are loaded in at different times you can end up with multiple bindings. Live events if used excessively can cause performance issues but here is a simple example of what can happen if you are not extremely careful executing your own bind events. http://jsfiddle.net/a8S8T/

Answer (score 4):

You should use `.live` because you are adding data dynamically

```
$('#ss').live('submit', function(evt) {
evt.preventDefault();
$.ajax({
url: 'yyy.php',
data: {
    query: $('#qq').val()
  },
success: function(data) {
    $('#rr').html(data);
  }
});
return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try handling newly loaded form `$('#sss').submit(function(evt) {});`